# How can I get my AIR (flash as3) app to display in full screen on Android?

Tags: android, air, adobe

At the moment it displays in a smaller window within the screen and makes most of the screen white. What I would like is for it to be stretched to fill the screen. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

during initialization of your application you can use [flash.system.Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html) to get the device's screen size and PPI for scaling / layout:

**Screen Width:**  [flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionX](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#screenResolutionX)

**Screen Height:**  [flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionY](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#screenResolutionY)

**Piexls-Per-Inch:**  [flash.system.Capabilities.screenDPI](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#screenDPI)